# How to clear Fatal error initializing 'com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.ManagingFS'

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-14

When i Tried to open android studio it throws the following error

Tried:
1. Restarting the system
2. Un-installing and reinstalling

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.ManagingFS'
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:224)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.lambda$initApplication$0(IdeaApplication.java:77)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:349)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.ManagingFS'
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.handleComponentError(PluginManager.java:258)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.PlatformComponentManagerImpl.handleInitComponentError(PlatformComponentManagerImpl.java:43)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:500)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:246)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:213)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.BasicComponentParameter.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:77)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ComponentParameter.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:114)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getConstructorArguments(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:118)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.doGetComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:89)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.instantiateGuarded(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:66)
    at com.intelli
```

Comment: Please provide a few details like, OS, Ram, Android studio version.

Comment: android studio 3.5.2,OS-Windows 10, 8Gb ram

Comment: Add the details to the question, so they are clearly visible.